# Aggregations in Marklogic 8 Java

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I'm trying to group all the documents based on an element value. Through X-Query, I'm able to get the element value and its corresponding count. But, with Java API I'm not able to do that.

X-Query:

```
for $name in distinct-values(doc()/document/<element_name>)
return fn:concat("Element Value:",$name,", Count:",fn:count(doc()/document/[element_name eq $name]));
```

Output:

```
Element Value:A, Count:100
Element Value:B, Count:200
```

Java:

```
QueryManager qryMgr = client.newQueryManager();
StructuredQueryBuilder qb = new StructuredQueryBuilder();
StructuredQueryDefinition querydef = qb.containerQuery(qb.element("<element_name>"), qb.term("A"));
SearchHandle handle = new SearchHandle();
qryMgr.search(querydef, handle);
System.out.println(handle.getTotalResults());
```

By this method, I'm able to get the document count only for a particular value. Is there any way to get the count of all documents. Kindly Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your use case, you can use a range index to solve this problem, which is - you want to know what all the values are for a particular element, and then how many documents have that value. That's exactly what a range index is for.

Try adding a range index on "element_name" - you can use the ML Admin app for that - go to your database and click on Element Range Indexes.

In XQuery, you can then do something like this:

```
for $val in cts:element-values(xs:QName("element_name"))
return text{$val, cts:frequency($val)}
```

With the Java Client, you can do the same by adding a range-based constraint to a search options file, and then the response from SearchManager will have all of the values and frequencies in it that match your query. Check the REST API docs for constructing such a search options file.

Comment: Works fine with XQuery. If possible, can you please share sample Java code with options as well. Because, I'm new to Marklogic. Thanks!

Comment: See http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_24780 for examples of how to setup a range index and query it. And see http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_65191 for how to do the same thing in Java.